# @dayclick does nothing in v-date-picker

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

I have a component date picker, and I'm working to pass the `date` data to my parent component, but events won't work. I tried other events too, but it won't work.

```html
<template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="date">
        <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
            <input class="bg-white px-2 py-1 rounded"
              placeholder="DATE"
              :value="inputValue"
              v-on="inputEvents"
              @dayclick="onDayClick"
            />
        </template>
    </v-date-picker>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            date: new Date(),
            masks: {
                input: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onDayClick() {
            console.log("hello");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@dayclick="onDayClick"` attempts to register an event listener on the `<input>` for an event named `"dayclick"`, but there's no such event for `HTMLInputElement`.

It looks like you're really trying to listen to `VCalendar`'s `dayclick` event, so the event listener should be on `<v-date-picker>` instead of `<input>`:

```html
<!--
<v-date-picker>
  <template>
    <input @dayclick="onDayClick">
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ❌
-->

<v-date-picker @dayclick="onDayClick">
  <template>
    <input>
```

Your `dayclick` handler could emit the selected date to the parent component with `$emit`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onDayClick(date) {
      this.$emit("date-selected", date); 
    },
  },
};
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/listening-to-day-clicks-in-v-calendars-date-picker-940iq?file=/src/App.vue:11-67)

Comment: @JoshuaLictan See updated answer for `$emit` example.